# React with Typescript - Type { } is missing the following properties from type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I'm trying to learn React with TypeScript, and I seem to keep running into TS errors that are a bit vague.

I have code written below in three files, which works fine when compiled and run. I just keep getting this error thrown by TypeScript that is super annoying

> "Type '{ id: any; key: any; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ProfileCardProps': login, name"

// Form.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';

export default class Form extends React.Component<any,any>{
  constructor(props: any){
    super(props);
    this.state = { userName: ""};
  }

  handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<EventTarget>): void => {
    event.preventDefault();

   //get request...
    .then(resp => {
        this.props.onSubmit(resp.data);
    console.log(resp.data);
    this.setState({userName: ''});
  };

  public render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <div className="col-sm-12">
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label>Run lookup:<br />
              <input type="text"
                value = {this.state.userName}
                onChange = {(event) => this.setState({userName: event.target.value})}
                placeholder = "Enter Username..." >
              </input>
            </label>
            <button type="submit">Add user info</button>
          </form>
          <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

}
```

// Card.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface ProfileCardProps{ 
  login: string; 
  name: string; 
}

const ProfileCard = (props: ProfileCardProps) => {

  return(
    <div className="card col-xs-1 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <div className="profileWrapper">
        <div className="userName">
          <p>{props.login}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="user">
          <h3>{props.name}</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

const CardList = (props: { cards: { map: (arg0: (card: any) => JSX.Element) => React.ReactNode; }; }) => {
    return(
      <div className="row">

         // This is the line that is throwing the error
        {props.cards.map((card: { id: any; }) => <ProfileCard key={card.id} {...card} />)}
      </div>
    )
}

export default CardList;
```

//ProfileList

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Form from './Form';
import CardList from './ProfileCard';

import "./ProfileStyles.scss";

export default class Profiles extends React.Component<any, any>{
state = {
    cards: [
      { login: "exampleLogin",
        name:"exampleName",
        key: 1
      },
      { login: "exampleLogin2",
        name:"exmapleName2",
        key: 2
      }
    ]
  }

  addNewCard = (cardInfo: any) => {
    this.setState((prevState: { cards: { concat: (arg0: any) => void; }; }) => ({
      cards: prevState.cards.concat(cardInfo)
    }));
  }


  public render() {
    return(
      <div className="cardSection">
        <h2>Profiles</h2> 
        <Form onSubmit={this.addNewCard} />
        <CardList cards={this.state.cards} />
      </div>
    )
  };
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As you are passing card to ProfileCard component, its passing 4 values in props.

```
{login: string, name: string, key: number, id: number}
```

But your interface has only 2

```
interface ProfileCardProps{ 
  login: string; 
  name: string; 
}
```

Adding key and id should solve the issue.

```
interface ProfileCardProps{ 
  login: string; 
  name: string;
  id:any;
  key: any;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This type of use of an interface requires that all members of the interface be null

```
interface ProfileCardProps{ 
  login: string; 
  name: string;
  id?:number; 
}
```

Comment: Not really, this is not the meaning

Answer (score 0):

I've spent about an hour to figure out the similar error message and finally understood that I forgot to import the appropriate interface :) Maybe it will be helpful for someone...